# Can I attach a Marionette collection view to existing HTML?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections, view, marionette

I'm using browserify with node to render out a collection on the server, then using Marionette on the client side.

Is it possible to use Marionette regions attachView() to attach a CollectionView to the existing html list?

Answer (score 3):

Marionette doesn't provide a way to do this through the standard API but it is possible using some of Marionette's internal `CollectionView` methods. I've provided an example here:

http://jsbin.com/zirupeli/1/edit

The key part is the `createChildren` function in the CollectionView:

```
var List = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
  el: 'ul',

  itemView: Item,

  initialize: function() {
    this.createChildren();
  },

  createChildren: function() {
    this.collection.each(function(model) {
      var view = new this.itemView({
        el: 'li:eq(' + (model.get('id') - 1) + ')',
        model: model
      });

      // set up the child view event forwarding
      this.addChildViewEventForwarding(view);

      // Store the child view itself so we can properly
      // remove and/or close it later
      this.children.add(view);
    }, this);
  }
});
```

Here we just create an `ItemView` for each item in the collection and then call two internal Marionette `CollectionView` methods: `this.addChildViewEventForwarding` and `this.children.add`. These are used by Marionette internally when it renders child views:

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/lib/backbone.marionette.js#L1687

Just to prove that this is working correctly, after four seconds you should notice that an item gets added to the list and after eight seconds the first item in the list is removed.

Comment: Had to use `model.id` instead of `model.get('id')`, but otherwise worked brilliantly. Thanks.

Comment: I really wish this still worked, as I am seriously struggling with this myself :(

Comment: @Designermonkey my answer was for an older version of the Marionette API. You can still do it with the most recent version like this: https://gist.github.com/stephendeyoung/89f7537558a83f72ea1f

Answer (score 0):

As of version 2.0.0 the addChildViewEventForwarding function has been removed.

Replace...

```
this.addChildViewEventForwarding(view);
```

With...

```
this.proxyChildEvents(view);
```

I know, I too would have preferred to comment on the answer provided by @StephenYoung but I don't have the reputation.  Still a padawan.